# QT compiling for Debian systems

Tags: bitcoin-qt-setup

```
Bitcoin version : 0.21
System: Ubuntu 18.04
```

All dependencies installed.

I am using Depends system to compile QT wallet. I compiled all three (Mac, Windows, and Ubuntu) successfully. All run just fine.

Only with Ubuntu, the QT file doesn't open with double click like other programs. How do I compile it so it works just like other programs, and I don't have to open terminal every time I want to run the QT wallet.

Comment: What happens instead when you open by double clicking? Maybe it's just already running? Can you run bitcoin-qt from the command line?

Comment: yes, everytime I want to run the QT wallet, I open the terminal and type ./bitcoin-qt to run it. It runs perfectly fine.

Comment: It is mentioned in these links [1](https://forum.qt.io/topic/97822/no-application-installed-for-shared-library-files/2) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329372/ubuntu-recognizes-executable-as-shared-library-and-wont-run-it-by-clicking?answertab=active#tab-top) that `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -no-pie` should be present in `.pro` file. There was a `bitcoin-qt.pro` in [/contrib](https://github.com/prayank23/gui/blob/dark-theme/contrib/bitcoin-qt.pro) few months back. Not sure why I don't see it right now in [Master branch](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui/tree/master/contrib).

Comment: @Prayank That sounds unrelated to being able to start it by double clicking. Clearly the binary works, or OP wouldn't be able to start it from the command line.

Comment: @Prayank About bitcoin-qt.pro, see https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21695

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link. I am not sure but adding `bitcoin-qt.pro` again and saving the thing I mentioned might fix this issue for Ubuntu. The file will also be helpful if we implement dark theme for qt. Will try and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: I am not saying binary doesn't work. I am saying I want to open it with double click instead of going to terminal. Just like if I download Bitcoin-qt from Ubuntu app store, or from Github release page.

Comment: here's the exact error when I double click the Bitcoin-qt binary file:
There is no application installed for "shared library" files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

Comment: @prayank That file is for Qt creator. It is not used for building binaries.

Comment: @PieterWuille I was following the things mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332687/ but it didn't work for Bitcoin Core

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

1. Create a file `bitcoin-qt.desktop`
2. Save below content in the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=bitcoin-qt
Comment=Bitcoin Core
Exec=bitcoin-qt
Icon=bitcoin.png
Terminal=false
```

3. Save [`bitcoin.png`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/qt/res/icons/bitcoin.png) in `/usr/share/icons`
4. Right click on `bitcoin-qt.desktop`, go to permissions and allow executing file as program
5. Double clicking `bitcoin-qt.desktop` will launch `bitcoin-qt`

Comment: Yes, I know of this workaround. But what if I want to send the compiled binary file to someone else? They too will need to create this file, right ? that's what I am trying to avoid. I am trying to have a ready-to-use compiled binary that doesn't need any further configs

Comment: @gladiator9120 Then you should use the depends build system (see the readme in the depends subdirectory), it is a build system that compiles with the exact same dependencies and configuration as Bitcoin Core's release binaries.

Comment: @PieterWuille Yes, I am using Depends system, but yet it is not executable.

Comment: @Gladiator9120 an AppImage might also work in this case.